# How to add google angle to cmake project using vcpkg?

Tags: c++, cmake, opengl-es, vcpkg, google-angle

I have a project using opengl es and I wanted to transfer it to google angle. I downloaded angle via vcpkg. But I ran into a problem with cmake not seeing the headers from angle.

What I've done:

- Change CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to vcpkg file.
- Add this to my cmake:

```
find_package(unofficial-angle CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(Anterle PRIVATE 
    unofficial::angle::libEGL 
    unofficial::angle::libGLESv2
)
```

- Use this headers:

```
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES3/gl3.h>
```

Comment: ye same. cant help u sorry but I'll follow this